# "Reconnaissance by fire" non-warfare version?

Tags: idioms, phrase-request, idiom-request

You have to solve a problem.
It won't be easy.
You can say the process of solving the problem will take a lot of resources you don't have - typically the knowledge.

In military this is called [reconnaissance by fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconnaissance_by_fire). In everyday life, when dealing with your super extra convoluted tricky problem you sigh "Oh well, let's go... this will be a *recon by fire*. :-( "

How to sigh without the warfare term?

Comment: *Trial by fire* may be what you are looking for.

Comment: An alternative to war here is religion. It will be a *baptism by fire*. But even that phrase is used in military contexts, a soldier's first time in battle. You could say "oh well, it's *sink or swim*" to refer to the need to plunge in, despite a lack of readiness.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I think though that "trial by fire" and "baptism by fire" is more about getting experience by getting [tossed in the deep end](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/throw+someone+in+at+the+deep+end) and less about gaining knowledge of the situation by firing blind.

Comment: @ColleenV : But taking on a problem you're not prepared for is analogous to being tossed (or jumping) into the deep end.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Sure, but that’s not the same sense that “recon by fire” has. recon by fire is shooting toward areas wherever you think the enemy is and seeing if anyone shoots back.

Comment: I'm responding to OP's scenario: "You have to solve a problem. It won't be easy. You can say the process of solving the problem will take a lot of resources you don't have - typically the knowledge."

Comment: _trial by fire_ and _baptism by fire_ are IMHO more on "testing" rather than on advance.
To give an example: you've been working for some time for your company and people trust in your capabilities in general. That's why your boss told you to do a technical task nobody knows anything about - the black box approach. You have to figure the problem out by trying something and see if you get expected results. In the end you both understand the problem and you also solve it (and can share the knowledge).
_sink or swim_, _being thrown in at the deep end_ work better for me, but still... ?

Answer (score 1):

My unique suggestion:

> [Dead man walking](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dead+man+walking).

This idiom describes someone who is doomed despite all appearances to the contrary.

Applied to your example with your boss and coworkers *(Dec. 19 '17 at 16:38)*, the worker could be showing up to work, talking to coworkers, and going about their day as usual on a superficial level. The reality, however, would be that the assignment is nearly impossible to complete, and that the worker will fail and suffer the consequences.

Some less-precise, non-warfare equivalents, previously suggested in the comments:

> Being thrown in the deep end (or the lion's den).
>
> Sink or swim.